# data is not fetching more than one time Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have two buttons (tab) and i want to fetch different data after click on these tabs
code is working one time(after refresh page) but if i again click on tab then nothing displaying
Here is my current code

```
const Post = ({ post, blogs }) => {
     // for latest data
     const [students2,setStudents2] = useState({
        data: [], //change string to array
        loading: true
      })
    
        const handleClick2 = async() => {
               var spath=router.asPath;
                 const response = await axios.get(`https://xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx`)
                setStudents2({
                data: response.data,
                loading: false
            })
    }
}

    // for pinned
        const [students,setStudents] = useState({
            data: [], //change string to array
            loading: true
          })
        
            const handleClick = async() => {
                   var spath=router.asPath;
                     const response = await axios.get(`https://xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx`)
                    setStudents({
                    data: response.data,
                    loading: false
                })
        }
    }
<a className="nav-link active" onClick={(e) => handleClick5(e)}>Newest</a>
<a className="nav-link" onClick={(e) => handleClick2(e)}>pined</a>
```

for fetch data i am using following code

```
{students2.data?.length > 0 &&
    students2.data.map((blog) => (
        // fetch pinneddata
    }
    {students.data?.length > 0 &&
        students.data.map((blog) => (
            // fetch latest data
        }
```

Comment: You must give different name to your handleClicks functions. React can't choose the right one

Comment: @Johan i did right , i typed mistakenly , updated my question

Comment: you use <a> tag for button, <a> tag default behavior refresh the page when clicked. have you checked when you click second-time function is called or not? in one button you called handleClick5 it should be handleClick. I would like to see how you render return data in jsx can you share that code.